# Google plus pulling in Schema data on wordpress?

Tags: schema, facebook-opengraph

So i am using the open graph method to pull in content from a Wordpress site that can then be posted on facebook. However with google plus the content that is pulled in is distorted. It is pulling in the title twice and the content twice. So i opted to use Schema.org. Open graph has meta tags which are invisible on the site while Schema uses regular html tags as follows:

```
<div itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/Movie">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Avatar</h1>
  <span>Director: <span itemprop="director">James Cameron</span> (born August 16, 1954)</span>
  <span itemprop="genre">Science fiction</span>
  <a href="../movies/avatar-theatrical-trailer.html" itemprop="trailer">Trailer</a>
</div>
```

This displays on my site so i added an inline style of "display: hidden;" to the div. However this doesn't work. Has anyone gotten schema to work with Wordpress? Or a better question might be, has anyone gotten open graph/schema to work with google plus?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`display: hidden;` does not exist. You're looking for `display: none;`

http://jsfiddle.net/wgLZL/